# What's wrong with my solution to an inital value ODE problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following is a problem from Weinberger textbook "A first course in partial differential equations".

[image]

The answer key is $u=\log x$. I have spent three hours on this problem but still cannot reach the same result. The following is my solution. I checked it many times and it looks correct to me. Can anyone help look what is wrong with my solution? Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not the easiest thing to read; you may want to consider using MathJax to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but when finding the functions $c_1(\xi)$ and $c_2(\xi)$ you appear to assume that these functions must be real, which is not guaranteed *a priori.*